# Tomcat doesnt show the pages with cluster and apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I am doing a cluster configuration and I read everything but I have a big problem, I did all configurations and I read all information on the web but I have problem yet.
My problem is when I try to use 
http://192.168.56.101/examples 
it show me the page with examples but when I click to any example, Servlet for example, I get the error 404, example when I click servlet 
http://192.168.56.101/servlets I get the 404 error.
If I press F5 the its refresh well but any button that I use get 404 ,seems
like it doesnt know the other pages.
I am using examples that come with Tomcat8 to test cluster Tomcat8 + Java8 + Apache 2.4+ DEbian 7

Any cluees ?

Comment: Can you share your setup? If you connect Apache and Tomcat, which parts of the application are forwarded to the tomcat server? Maybe it would be best if you gave the tomcat another HTTP connector (say... 8080?) and run your  tests on http://182.168.56.101:8080/examples that way you'd know which part of your setup needs checking

Comment: if you are seeing ==>HTTP Status 404 - /examples

type Status report
message /examples

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 then it means Tomcat is working but you not configured the path of tomcat examples in your configuration files. I agree with @Jan. Please update your question and show us configuration files to pin point the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here


<IfModule jk_module>

JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties

JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log

# Our JK log level (trace,debug,info,warn,error)
JkLogLevel info

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"

# Our JK shared memory file
JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status

JkWatchdogInterval 60

<Location /jk-status>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
<Location /jk-manager>
    # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
    JkMount jk-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

JkMount  /* loadbalancer
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps=/
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true

worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status

worker.list=loadbalancer

worker.server1.port=8009
worker.server1.host=localhost
worker.server1.type=ajp13
worker.server1.lbfactor=1

worker.server2.port=8010
worker.server2.host=localhost
worker.server2.type=ajp13
worker.server2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=server1,server2
worker.jkstatus.type=status
```

## -----Virtalhost apache--------

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

JkMountCopy On

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```